# Loading Contents from one Layout to another

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working on JSF;
I have got two layouts, top layout and center layout, in the top layout i got menu as shown as given in code, my target is when i click on the any menuitem in the top layout the url attached to that menu item is displayed in the center layout

Following is my Code:

```
 <p:layout fullPage="true">
<!-- Top Layout -->
 <p:layoutUnit position="north" style="overflow:hidden;height:30;">
  <h:form>
     <p:menubar style="font-size:12px;height:30;border:0;" >
             <p:submenu label="File" >
        </p:submenu>
         <p:submenu label="Edit">
         </p:submenu>
         <p:submenu label="Help">
        </p:submenu>
         <p:submenu label="Actions" >
         </p:submenu>
        <p:menuitem value="Quit" url="www.xyz.com"/>
        </p:menubar>
        </h:form>
     </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="cLay">
    <h:form id="cForm">
            <p:panel id="cPanel">
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
     </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

your guidance will be highly appreciated

Comment: Are we talking about jsf-1.2 or jsf-2 here? Can't be both?

Comment: working on jsf2.0 and primeface 3.5

Comment: I think [templating](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/) would be the solution you're searching for.

Comment: Please stop tagging JSF 2.x questions with `[jsf-1.2]`! JSF 2.x and 1.x are a fundamentally so different that it's impossible to give a single answer which covers both versions.